# Select an item, total no of times this item is repeated in database and no of times the status of this item is one

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a products in products table with status broken or not broken.

I need an sql query which show 
productid, total no of this this item is in table , times its status was one,

```
e-g  product_id  |  tottal_no_of_products_oF_this_type  | broketn
        5                   10                          |   3

SELECT   product_id,
         COUNT(product_id) AS duplicate_column, product_status
FROM     products_stored where product_status=broken
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY COUNT(product_id) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close. You can get the broken ones using conditional aggregation. For example:

```
select
  product_id,
  count(*) as total_no_of_products_this_type,
  sum(case when product_status = 'broken' then 1 else 0 end as broken
from products_stored
group by product_id
order by count(*) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
SELECT   product_id,
         COUNT(product_id) over(partition by product_status) AS duplicate_column, product_status
FROM     products_stored where product_status=broken
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: over(partition by product_status)  can you please explain this statement